# How can I include greek letters as node names in R

Tags: r, igraph

My objective is to write greek letters on node names with R. I'm using igraph, so I don't know if it's possible with it. In that case I would like another one in order to do it.

Comment: You need to show the code and data you're using.

Comment: just pass the labels as an expression; `plot(graph_from_literal(a-b), vertex.label=expression(alpha, beta))`